# Como fazer com que ao criar varios imageview , ele ir para o lado do outro?

Tags: android

Como fazer com que ao criar varios imageview , ele ir para o lado do outro , e ao acabar o espaço na coluna ele passar para a próxima? tentei usar o linear porém quando acaba a coluna , ele continua colocando na mesma coluna , e diminuindo o tamanho para que caiba tudo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.paivadeveloper.lolvoices.AhriActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_ahri"
android:background="@color/corFundo">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="30dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ahriicon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ahriicon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ahriicon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ahriicon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ahriicon" />


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu consegue fazer isso utilizando um `RecyclerView`.

Voce vai criar um adapter, que vai gerenciar quando voce adicionar uma nova imagem para que abra um novo quadrado do lado. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

**RecycleImageAdapter**

```
public class RecycleImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Uri> itens;
boolean view;

public RecycleImageAdapter(Context context, List<Uri> itens, boolean view){
    this.context = context;
    this.itens = itens;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_add, viewGroup, false);
    RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder mvh = new RecycleImageAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    return mvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Uri imagem = itens.get(position);
    prepare(viewHolder, imagem, position);

}

private  void  prepare(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final Uri imagem, int position){
    if(imagem != null) {

   // Aqui tu vai exibir a sua imagem utilizando Picasso, Fresco ou afins

    }else{
        viewHolder.imageadd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return itens.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener{

    ImageView image;
    ImageView imageadd;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image = ((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image));
        imageadd = ((ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageadd));

    }
  }
```

e na sua Activity, tu vai colocar um `RecyclerView` onde voce quer exibir as imagens, e ficaria assim:

**XML**

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/lista">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**Activity**

```
        RecyclerView lista = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        lista.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    //Aqui voce vai setar quantos itens por coluna quer exibir
    lista.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));

    imagens.add(null);

    imageAdapter = new RecycleImageAdapter(this, imagens,false);
    lista.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

Como pode ver, quando voce adicionar uma nova imagem, deve adicionar outro item na lista com valor `null`, pois é ele quem vai criar o proximo quadradinho do lado.

**Item XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageadd"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Item xml é meu xml do adapter.

Comment: Então eu crio uma classe separada e coloco o recyclerimageadapter né? Esse recyclercview eu substituo o linear layout por ele ?

Comment: Isso amigo, o `adapter` é uma classe separada.  No caso do recycler no lugar do linear, ai vai de seu layout. O que deve tirar sao todos os image buttons.

Comment: Coloco o image button dentro do recycler né

Comment: Vale ressaltar também que eu tratei meu adapter para 2 image views diferentes. Uma chamada _image_, e outra _imageadd_. No seu caso, vc pode utilizar apenas 1 e na hora de comparar, mostrar um placeholder caso image seja `null`

Comment: eu editei minha resposta colocando o _itemadd_, layout que tu vai utilizar no adapter